# while($query->fetch()) both working and not working

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, image, while-loop

I'm working on a site which displays a blog and a photo gallery, which both get all their data from a MySQL-database using the same code (see below).

```
<?php
include_once("sql/db_connect.php");

$query1 = $db->prepare("SELECT post_id, title, body, img, timeposted FROM blogposts ORDER BY post_id DESC");
$query2 = $db->prepare("SELECT img_id, imgsrc FROM gallery ORDER BY img_id DESC");

$query1->execute();
$query2->execute();

$query1->bind_result($post_id, $title, $body, $img, $timeposted);
$query2->bind_result($img_id, $imgsrc);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>

    <header>...</header>

    <main>
        <div class="container">

            <div>
                <!-- Choose between tabs -->
            </div>

            <div class="wrapper1">
                <?php
                    while($query1->fetch()):
                ?>
                <div class="w3-col s12 m6">
                    <div class="card w3-depth-1">
                        <div class="cardheader">
                            <?php echo $timeposted ?>
                            <span>&#xe12a;</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="cardmain">
                            <div class="cardtext">
                                <h1><?php echo $title ?></h1>
                                <p><?php echo $body ?></p>
                            </div>
                            <?php 
                                if($img !== "NOPE") {
                                    echo "<img src='uploads/" . $img . "' class='blogimage' />";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile?>
            </div>

            <div class="wrapper2">
                <?php
                    while($query2->fetch()):
                ?>
                <div class="w3-col s12 m6">
                    <?php echo "<img src='uploads/" . $imgsrc . "' class='galleryphoto' />"; ?>
                </div>
                <?php endwhile?>
            </div>

        </div>
    </main>

    <footer>...</footer>

</body>
```

The div "wrapper1" is used for the blog, "wrapper2" for the gallery and at the top of the page there is a button which lets you switch between views (using jQuery). So on default, wrapper1 is displayed, but on clicking the button it will switch to wrapper2.

Now, my problem: in wrapper1, all blogposts are displayed, but in wrapper2, none of the pictures stored in the database are displayed at all.

And, before you ask, yes, the table is actually called "gallery" and the values are actually called "img_id" and "imgsrc". I guess I've checked that about ten times already.

When I placed "echo 'Hello World';" before the second while loop, the page said Hello World, but when I placed it in the while loop, the page still didn't display anything; that said, it shouldn't be the jQuery, I guess.

I hope that anybody can point out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance! If there's any additional data / code you need to have, I'd be happy to provide that.

Comment: This questions title would make Schrodinger proud.

Comment: SELECT img_id, imgsrc FROM gallery ORDER BY img_id DESC  try this query in mysql and see it it retrieve a record or not??

Comment: Is there any entry in `gallery`?

Comment: i am just guessing, but... : you could try to handle your queries one after the other: prepare, execute, bind, fetch for the first, then for the second. That is: i am guessing that your quieries interfere.

Comment: You appear to be missing a semi colon after each of the endwhile statements.

Comment: Thanks all! Burki's suggestion worked. I moved the queries from the head to their respective wrappers and everything's fixed. Also, Kickstart, thanks for the semicolon note. I didn't know that (and apparently PHP didn't as well, as it didn't give an error for that). Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, and if you add it as an answer, I guess I'll be able to mark it as one :).